Submit Pull Request on Github as part of CI/CD in Gitlab
I have several projects that my client maintains on gitlab. However, in order to push them to live, we have to merge the contents into a monorepo on github. Our current workflow is manual and looks like this:

Merge our new code into our repo on gitlab.
Checkout a new branch of our fork of the monorepo on github
Copy the changed files into the folder for our project in the monorepo
commit changes and push to our fork
Go to the original fork of the mono repo and submit a pull request from the new branch of our fork.

Is there any way to run automated CI/CD in gitlab/github that would do any or all of the above?

This sounds doable in a few lines ain a shell script using git and the github API. Infact you already know how to do the process manually, so just put those steps into a script like git clone https//...., git switch -c branch-xyz, cp src_files dest_dir, git commit -am "blah", then I am sure there will be agithub API to create a merge request

Wouldn't it easier to mirror the gitlab repo to GH unless the PR on GH needs to go through separate but specific reviews/workflows?
